# Firebase realtime DB - Create rule that limits size of child object

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I've got a Realtime Database where users can write data to a certain key. However, I want to avoid a potentially malicious user from inserting a huge amount of data, without creating any new middleware.

Here are my rules right now:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    /*
     * Only let people read a specific name 
     * Only let people write "$user": <public info json> or "$user": null
    */
    "$user": {
      ".read": "true",
      ".write": "auth.uid === $user"
      ".validate": "newData.val().length <= 123456 || newData.val() == null"
    }
  }
}
```

But this **incorrectly rejects** a write if the data at `databaseurl/$user` is **a child object** rather than a string, even if the JSON string representation of the child is below the length size.

How can I restrict the length of a child object, if the child is more than a simple string?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but it's really hard to understand questions about security rules without seeing the corresponding code that triggers the problem. Can you show the write operation that fails unexpected, and any JSON that needs to be in the database already for it to trigger?

Comment: I'm just playing with the Rules simulator

Comment: In that case, please show the same information in a screenshot of the rules playground. Make sure to include the exact data you're writing to the exact path, and the existing data at that path.